# How to scrape data from cell in a web table after login?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I need to scrape the content of a single cell in a table that is hosting on a web page available by the login. 
I used selenium to simulate the login-in in the web page and it worked, but now I don't know how can I extract the single information I need from the table.

The code I used to extract the info with BS doesn't work.
Please, forgive stupid errors, I am new with Python!

**Here is my code:**

```
#Scraping of single cell information
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

page = urllib.request.urlopen('https://services.7pixel.it/Invoices/Index') 
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

Fattura = soup.find('td:nth-child(3)') #I use the "copy selector" option in the chrome dev console

print(Fattura)
```

Comment: Can you please share the html of the table including the tr and td.

Comment: please explain what doesn't work means? Also, when sharing the html using snippet tool via [edit] remember to tell us which value you expect to retrieve.